# sysmlink error when installing tensorflow/tfjs-node

Tags: tensorflow.js

I'm trying to install @tensorflow/tfjs-node@3.2.1 (latest).
I have follow a lot of other questions I saw regarding such problems but haven't found an answer for this specific issue.

I have installed visual studio with the requested build tools.

node 14.15.5

Tried with and without the flag.

This is the output of the install command:

```
$ npm install @tensorflow/tfjs-node --build-from-source
npm WARN deprecated node-pre-gyp@0.14.0: Please upgrade to @mapbox/node-pre-gyp: the non-scoped node-pre-gyp package is deprecated and only the @mapbox scoped package will recieve updates in the future

> @tensorflow/tfjs-node@3.2.0 install C:\Users\dark_\Desktop\projects\tfjs2\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node
> node scripts/install.js

CPU-windows-3.2.0.zip
* Downloading libtensorflow

* Building TensorFlow Node.js bindings
symlink ./lib/napi-v7 failed:  null
npm WARN tfjs2@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN tfjs2@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @tensorflow/tfjs-node@3.2.0 install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @tensorflow/tfjs-node@3.2.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dark_\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-27T18_14_41_492Z-debug.log
```

Comment: I am facing exact same issue, Have you found fix for this?

Comment: @FawazAhmed No, but I also posted a question here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/4761 hopefully I will get help there.

Answer (score 4):

After spening a day trying the usual suspects (node-gyp reinstall as global, windows building tools (re)install as global, parameter settings, etc) I've debugged the install script and found an error in it: after the symlink stuff, the author didn't check the "error" variable, and went straight to process.exit(1)

After I tore out my hair, I've found that the solution is on it's way:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/commit/2e745c8b6efe5ffc396a86cfc50347e629091248

It has been commited to the main branch (2021.02.26), so probably we'll see it in v3.3.0, or v3.2.x

Now the problem is, that if you just do a simple `npm install @tensorflow\tfjs-node`, the installer sees it as an error, and deletes the whole downloaded directory in `node_modules`. You COULD prevent the whole thing by:

- EXECUTING `npm install @tensorflow/tfjs-node --ignore-scripts`
- THEN correcting the error by hand in the install script (check the commit at the above link) and
- RUNNING `npm rebuild @tensorflow/tfjs-node --build-from-source`.

I needed to restart VSCode, because it had difficulties picking up the references. But if you don't want to mess arround, go back to the v2.x branch for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

Install visual studio build tools for c++.
After, try: npm install `@tensorflow/tfjs-node`.

If errors , confirm if python 2.7 is installed,

```
set npm_config_python=C:\Python27\python.exe
```

Try again:

```
npm install @tensorflow/tfjs-node
```